# why set both className and class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am no longer sure why I do this. I read somewhere that i should set both class and className

Why both? why not just "class". I am just trying to understand this, since every thing seems to work just fine with "class".

```
$(e).attr('class','highlightMe');
$(e).attr('className','highlightMe');
```

---Update-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

So if I want to clear all classes first? there might be more then just one...
I would do something like this?

```
$(e).removeClass();
$(e).addClass('highlightMe');
```

---Update-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is what I ended up doing, it seems to be working fine...so far

The **attr** initializes the class... gets rid of other classes I might have in there

The **addClass** to add more classes

I could not use **removeClass**, because I am not referencing the element by ID

```
$(.base123).attr('class','base123');
$(.base123).addClass('highlightMe blinkMe');
```

Comment: jQuery's `.attr()` simulates the setting of an HTML attribute on the element you selected. Practically, an element can have multiple classes, so jQuery allows you to add and remove classes with dedicated `.addClass()` and `.removeClass` methods. `className` is the Javascript attribute for an element that contain classes data.

Comment: if you wanted to clear all classes, you can call .removeClass() (with no parameters) (I've updated my answer to address this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are wrong, well wrong is a strong word, there are more optimal approaches such as: With jQuery you only need [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).  If a class is already attached to the element then this won't do anything, if it isn't it will add it.  To address your update, calling [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) (with no parameters) will remove all classes on an element (or elements)

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is not correct.  The `.attr('className')` is indeed wrong, but the `.attr('class')` is correct.  Just because something isn't optimal or preferred doesn't mean it's wrong.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I had voted up your answer because it went farther than my initial "both a wrong" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `addClass` method to set the class to an element.

```
$(e).addClass('newClassName');
```

It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements

If you want to add multiple classes, you can seperate them with a space.

```
$("#theElementID").addClass("clsActive clsPremium");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Everyone is suggesting to use [these methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) (which you should), but that doesn't answer your question!**

The real answer is:  use `class` when you're using the `.attr()` method with jQuery, and use `className` when you're using the `.prop()` method or with plain JavaScript.

Javascript stores the classes as `element.className` to avoid keyword conflict, but using `$(element).attr('class')` actually changes the HTML attribute (which is linked to the DOM element's className property, so they stay in sync).

**EDIT: To answer your update**

Use either `e.className=''` or `$(e).attr('class','')` or `$(e).prop('className','')` or just `$(e).removeClass()` (no argument) to clear the classes from an element.

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('class', 'foo')` would wipe out any other classes set on your target element. as stated above, `.addClass('foo')` would, as it suggests, add the class to your target element, thus preserving any others currently set.

**however**

I think what you may be asking, has to do with this:

`$('<div />', {'class' : 'bar});` vs `$('<div />', {className : 'bar'});`

which are affectively the same thing— [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) is unrelated to jQuery, it's simply vanilla Javascript.

So, `$(foo).attr('class', 'bar');` 
is simply

`$(foo).className = 'bar';`

or more literally:

`$(foo).setAttribute('class', 'bar');`

or even *more* literally:

`document.getElementById('foo').className = 'bar';`

`document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('class', 'bar');`